# pgAdmin 4 v 7.1 not loading after trying everything

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am having serious problems getting pgAdmin 4 to load.  I'm running on Windows 10.  Please see attached screenshot.  I have naturally tried to troubleshoot this problem myself.  I have followed instructions from a google search to change the .js content type to have the value text/javascript in the registry editor and then closed pgadmin and its servers in task manager.  Annoyingly I still get the same error message.

I previously tried to install postgreSQL about 2 months ago and then deleted it.  Could it be that I have somehow caused a problem.  I uninstalled postgreSQL by right clicking on it and clicking uninstall.

What else coud I try to troubleshoot this problem? Thank you

[image]

[image: The error message]

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `psql`. It works reliably and is much more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

I installed pgAdmin 4 directly from an exe file and that seems to have worked. I don't understand why it wouldn't install properly as part of the postgresq package but problem solved.  :)

Edit : The link to working pgAdmin 4 is https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/